# tabs in android

Tags: android

hi how can i set tab in both bottom and top of the same screen.i need to display the one tab in top of the screen and another one in the bottom of the same screen.any body know how to do it   thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of design is that??? Tabs both at bottom and top??

Comment: I think its not good design practice. Neways you can use buttons on top+bottom , not tabs to accomplish this.

Comment: you can't set you need to specify one position either top or bottom for tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi rakesh you can use the link to set a tab on bottom [custom tabs](http://code.google.com/p/androidtabs/)
and also look at this sample code

```
public class Tab App extends Tab Activity {
```

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
    tabHost.removeAllViews();
    TabWidget tabs = new TabWidget(this);
    tabs.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    tabs.setLayoutParams(params);
    FrameLayout content = new FrameLayout(this);
    content.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
    content.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relative.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    relative.addView(content);
    relative.addView(tabs);
    tabHost.addView(relative);
    tabHost.setup();

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidBrowser.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1")
      .setIndicator("tag1",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.cw))
                              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CWBrowser.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2")
      .setIndicator("tag2",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.cw))
                              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CWBrowser.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag3")
      .setIndicator("tag3",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.cw))
                              .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}`
```

Comment: hi araf thanks for your help, but this code will display the tab in bottom only,i want to display both  top and bottom tab,both in same screen